# SVN - can't check out a file previously deleted and then restored in the repo

Tags: file, svn, svn-checkout

There're files/folders that were deleted and then re-added to the repository.

svn update > gives me the right-updated revision.
files and folders are correctly displayed in the svn repository, if I run 'svn update' 'svn diff' my workspace folder seems in sync but the files/folders are not checked out...
any idea of what the problem is?

If I check out the project from scratch once again the files/folders are checked out correctly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might be running into the following [problem](http://www.nabble.com/Update-doesn%27t-fetch-new-files-in-1.6.1-td23204589.html)

From the article:

> With an 1.6.1 client, there's a
>   situation where new files aren't
>   fetched in an update.
>
> This happens when adding a new folder
>   with --depth=empty, which is what TSVN
>   uses to avoid that files which the
>   user doesn't want to add get added
>   automatically too. See the comments in
>   the script.

The solution (thanks wcoenen):

```
svn update --set-depth infinity
```

Comment: +1 but you didn't mention the solution: `svn update --set-depth infinity`

Answer (score 0):

I would try to do a clean 'svn checkout'. Sometimes the local information is not properly in sync in causes this kind of effects.

Comment: the fact is that if I run 'svn checkout [folder]' it says. Checked out revision xxx. But the local folder doesn't contain the files that are listed in svn. by command line looks like in sync but it is not.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Try to cleanup the folder]

[image: Remember to check "Revert All Changes Recursively"]

If you are using TortoiseSVN, you can try to use Clean up feature in context menu.